# Force reszing of images

Tags: html, css, image-resizing

I'm trying to change the size of a list of images so that they are all the same size. The image size needs to be 233px by 250px, which may mean forcing an image to be larger or smaller than its original size. At the moment the image is just being cropped to 233px by 250px, resulting in larger original photos losing content at the bottom.

Heres the current css:

```
float: left;
max-width: 233px; 
max-height: 250px; 
width: auto; 
height: auto; 
border: 2px solid #333333;
margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #333333;
transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
```

Any help?

Comment: You'll have more control over this by using a regular element (e.g. a `div`) with a `background-image` (coupled with `background-size`) rather than an `img`.

Comment: Could you please add more information, specifically your html markup or a codepen. It's more than likely because overflow is set to hidden. Do make sure the images should all be the same ratio.

Comment: Server side image resizing gives much more satisfactory results that browser side

Comment: Hye guys, gamingwrld.com is where the said images are located. They are located in ".jcarousel li", thats where I think the problem is lieing.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, use of div might solve your problem :

**HTML :**

```
<div><img src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4706825697_c0367e6dee_b.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div><img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3766/12953056854_b8cdf14f21.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6092/6227418584_d5883b0948.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
div {
  width: 233px;
  height: 255px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1%;
  background: red;
}
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/gscerdLn/

Answer (score 1):

**Specify the** `width` and `height` **like below.**

```css
img{

max-width: 233px; 
max-height: 250px; 
width: 233px; 
height: 250px; 
border: 2px solid #333333;
margin: 5px;
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #333333;
transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4706825697_c0367e6dee_b.jpg" alt="">

<img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3766/12953056854_b8cdf14f21.jpg" alt="">

  <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6092/6227418584_d5883b0948.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `width` and `height` to `100%` instead of `auto` like this:

```
width: 100%; 
height: 100%;
```